# Issue when appending new items to a list

Tags: python, list, class, pygame, append

I am trying to make a random enemy spawner for my game. For that, I have seen this method on Stack Overflow but it does not seem to work for me, and I am not sure why. When appending the code to my list, for some reason it does not go through properly. Below is my relevant code for more clarification as to what I mean. The code between the hashtags are the ones to be highlighted

moveFunctions:

```
def moveFunctions(bullets, E_bullets, score, font, window,
                  protagR, protagL, protagU, protagD, enemyR, enemyL, enemyU, enemyD, bg):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    bulletSFX = pygame.mixer.Sound("ASG2_Music/shoot_Bullet_SFX.wav")
    getHitSFX = pygame.mixer.Sound("ASG2_Music/Hit_SFX.wav")
    enemy_getHitSFX = pygame.mixer.Sound("ASG2_Music/Monster_Hit_SFX.wav")
    music = pygame.mixer.music.load("ASG2_Music/stand_Proud.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

    bulletDelay = 0
    game_Over = True
    run = True
    ##########################################################################################
    DiArrow = enemy(random.randint(1, 500), random.randint(1, 500), 48, 48, 410)
    board = player(225, 225, 64, 64, 0)

    while run:
        enemies = []
        maxEnemies = 5
        for i in range(maxEnemies):
            enemies.append(enemy(random.randint(1, 500), random.randint(1, 500), 48,48, 410))
            print(enemies)
    ##########################################################################################
        if game_Over:
            # show_game_Over_Screen()
            game_Over = False
        clock.tick(15) # Frame rate per second (FPS)

        if bulletDelay > 0:
            bulletDelay += 1
        if bulletDelay > 3:
                bulletDelay = 0

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                stopGame()

        fireBullet(board, bullets, DiArrow, score, enemy_getHitSFX)
        E_fireBullet(board, E_bullets, DiArrow, getHitSFX)

        arrowKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        score = fireBullet(board, bullets, DiArrow, score, enemy_getHitSFX)

        bulletDirection(arrowKeys, board, bullets, bulletDelay, bulletSFX)
        bulletDelay = bulletDirection(arrowKeys, board, bullets, bulletDelay, bulletSFX)
        E_bulletDirection(DiArrow, E_bullets, board)
        playerControls(arrowKeys, board)
        enemyControls(DiArrow, board)
        redrawGameWindow(board, DiArrow, bullets, E_bullets, font, score, window, protagR, protagL, protagU, protagD,
                         enemyR, enemyL, enemyU, enemyD, enemies, bg)
```

redrawGameWindow:

```
def redrawGameWindow(board, DiArrow, bullets, E_bullets, font, score, window, protagR, protagL, protagU, protagD, enemyR,
                     enemyL, enemyU, enemyD, enemies, bg):
    window.blit(bg, (0,0))
    text = font.render("Score: " + str(score), 1, (255, 255, 255))
    window.blit(text, (340, 513))
    board.drawCharacter(window,  protagR, protagL, protagU, protagD)
    ##########################################################################################
    for i in enemies:
        DiArrow.drawEnemy(window, enemyR, enemyL, enemyU, enemyD)
    ##########################################################################################
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(window)
    for bullet in E_bullets:
        bullet.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()
```

class enemy():

```
class enemy():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, walkCount):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 3
        self.lastDirection = "right" or "left" or "up" or "down"
        self.walkCount = walkCount
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 48, 50)
        self.health = 4
        self.visible = True

    def drawEnemy(self, window, enemyR, enemyL, enemyU, enemyD):
        dest = (self.x, self.y)

        if self.visible:
            if self.walkCount + 1 >= 15:
                self.walkCount = 0

            if self.lastDirection == "left":
                window.blit(enemyL[self.walkCount//3], dest)
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.lastDirection == "right":
                window.blit(enemyR[self.walkCount//3], dest)
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.lastDirection == "up":
                window.blit(enemyU[self.walkCount//3], dest)
                self.walkCount += 1
            elif self.lastDirection == "down":
                window.blit(enemyD[self.walkCount//3], dest)
                self.walkCount += 1
            self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 48, 50)

            pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 15, 50, 10))
            pygame.draw.rect(window, (177, 0, 175), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 15, 50 - ((50/5)*(4 - self.health)), 10))

    def getHit(self):
        if self.health > 0:
            print("Enemy Got Hit!")
            self.health -= 1
        else:
            print("Enemy Killed!")
            self.visible = False

    def gameOver(self):
        if self.visible == False:
            pass
```

I have found that when trying to check for the error, printing enemies in moveFunctions actually does not properly print the list and instead gives out this.

```
[<__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3828>]
[<__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3828>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3470>]
[<__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3828>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3470>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3EB8>]
[<__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3828>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3470>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3EB8>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A39E8>]
[<__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3828>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3470>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3EB8>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A39E8>, <__main__.enemy object at 0x00000251C53A3048>]
```

As you can see, the list IS updating, but instead with this weird string of text I do understand.

For full disclosure, I am using the pygame module in Python, but I doubt that is what is giving me this problem here.

I am assuming here that my issue for the maxEnemies not spawning is directly linked with this one. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: You actually create a new enemy list in every frame and add 5 new `enemy` instances to the list.

Comment: The "weird string of text" is the `repr` of an `enemy` object. What do you expect to print out instead?

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually create a new enemy list (`enemies = []`) in every frame and add 5 new `enemy` instances to the list. Furthermore the list is printed in the loop.

Create the list of enemies before the main application loop and print the attributes of each single enemy rather than the list of enemies:

```py
def moveFunctions(.....):
    # [...]

    enemies = []
    maxEnemies = 5
    for i in range(maxEnemies):
        newEnemy = enemy(random.randint(1, 500), random.randint(1, 500), 48,48, 410)
        enemies.append(newEnemy)
        print(newEnemy.x, newEnemy.y)

    while run:
        # [...]
```

---

Note, [Class Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) should normally use the CapWords convention. Name the class `Enemy` rather than `enemy`:

<s>`class enemy():`</s>

```py
class Enemy():
```

Comment: Once again, you have my thanks Rabbid76. This worked, thank you